# Date Problems in R: replacement has x rows, data has y

Tags: r, date

I have an Excel Sheet (csv) in which the dates appear like this : `2015-01-29` (Year, Month, Date)

When I import this sheet into R, the dates automatically appear as "factor" type. Since I am using an older version of R (3.5.2) in which there are certain problems with factors/strings, I tried to convert the date using the following code:

```
file$date_var  = as.Date(as.character(file$date_var), format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Although this code produces no error messages, when I try to perform some operation on this date variable I get the following error:

```
file$new = ifelse(file$date_var > as.Date(as.character("2015-01-01"), format = "%Y/%m/%d"), "A", "B")

Error in ... replacement has x rows, data has y
```

- Is there a way I can resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Note: I am also exploring the "lubridate" library, e.g.

```
library(lubridate)

file$date_var = ymd(as.character(file$date_var))

file$new = ifelse(file$date_var > ymd(as.character("2015-01-01")), "A", "B")
```

But this is also not working...

Comment: It seems that you have the wrong format for your date. You need to write it like this: `as.Date(as.character("2015-01-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")`. Your format string must match the string of your entered date. Does this work?

Comment: @ Noah: some progress! But now everything this "new" variable (i.e. file$new) is all "A" when there should be some "A" and some "B". I wonder why this is happening? Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need `as.character` in your second call to `as.Date`, just `as.Date("2015-01-01")`.

Comment: What does `file$date_var > as.Date("2015-01-01")` return? You can see the proportions of each `>` and its negation with `mean(file$date_var > as.Date("2015-01-01"))`. Or better yet, `table(file$date_var > as.Date("2015-01-01"))`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas: mean(file$date_var > as.Date("2015-01-01")) returns a value of 1 ... but I don't think is correct because some of the dates are less than 2015-01-01.

Comment: That value doesn't leave margin for doubts, a mean of 1 means that all values are `TRUE`. Try to table like in the last code snippet.